# Compilation error due to a wrong creation of IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception, throw

I had written a code to show a billboard program and I wanted to prevent the system from crashing by using an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` when users enter an invalid choice. I can't seem to get it to run properly.

Here is what I have:

```
if (index <= messages.size())
    this.text = messages.get(index - 1);
else
    throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Invalid Number Choice");
```

Here is my error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - constructor IndexOutOfBoundsException in class java.util.IndexOutOfBoundsException cannot be applied to given types;
>    required: no arguments
>    found: `java.lang.String`
>    reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length.

I really don't know where to go from here. I tried try/catch and I can't use the `IndexOutOFBoundsException` which I wanted to use because I have another `Class` I'm calling.

Comment: Please provide your code. [`IndexOutOfBoundException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html) has such constructor, but the exception says you have `java.util.IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: You can't have an index out of bounds with an ArrayList, I get this idea because you have messages.size() in your code, and maybe try having curly braces in your code.

Comment: @Eran the exception class is `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException`. We don't know about `java.util.IndexOutOfBoundsException`, which seems to be a custom class made by OP which will fail because you cannot create a `java.<whatever>` package in your projects.

Comment: Don't modify the index, as it is confusing but also you will get `IndexOutOfBoundsException` for `index = 0;`.
Instead use `if (index < messages.size()) { this.text = messages.get(index) } else { throw ... }`

N.B. **less** instead of **less or equal**. You should also check for index to be non-negative to be correct.

Comment: I solved it. I changed it to a try..catch.                      public void setText(int index) throw StringIndexOutOfBoundsException; {
  try{ 
      (index <= messages.size())
        this.text = messages.get(index - 1);}
   
   catch (Exception e){

   System.out.println("Invalid Number Choice");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good that you are using a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException.

However, I should mention that based on your error " Uncompilable source code - constructor IndexOutOfBoundsException in class **java.util.IndexOutOfBoundsException**" You must have imported a different exception Class it should be **java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException**